# How to take into account empty groups in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, microsoft-reporting

I have asset conditions that I am graphing for my Council using Microsoft Report Builder and I can’t figure out a way to show categories that have no data against them. So below for instance, I have two examples of graphs of different asset types. The top graph has all of the categories I require (Excellent, Good, Fair, Poor and Failed), but the bottom graph is missing any examples of Failed assets. Is there any way that I can specify what categories must be included, so that blank ones are covered?

Example images:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSINY.png]

Comment: You need to have all of the categories represented in your data set that is used to populate the graph.  Can you post the query that populates the data set?

Comment: I have a bunch of diferent queries, but rather than solving this using SQL, i was hoping to be able to alter the axis somehow in order to get it to show the missing categories